# allow access to one page on sub-domain, and if tried accessing other pages redirect to main domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx

allow access to one page(`campaigns/test`) on sub-domain(`aap.example.com`), and if tried accessing other pages redirect to main domain(`example.com`)

`app.example.com` is my sub-domain of my main domain `example.com`, so same rails app is running on domain and sub-domain.

I tried some solutions like adding constraints in routes file and nginx file as well, but not getting what I need.

`routes.rb`

`constraints(Subdomain) do
    match '/campaigns/:slug' => 'campaigns#show', via: [:get]
    match "/cam_enquiry" => "campaigns#cam_enquiry", via: [:post]
  end`

and the `subdomain.rb` module

`class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    case request.subdomain
    when 'app', '', nil
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end
end`

Let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: Add your routes.rb, please

Comment: routes.rb changes added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define all your routes and after it define constraint for `app` subdomain. You need to match `test` route and use redirect for all other subdomain routes. Specify only blank subdomain in redirect parameters, in this case it will get all other info from request and only change subdomain to main domain

```
get 'campaigns/test', to: redirect(subdomain: 'app'), constraints: { subdomain: '' }
get '/campaigns/:slug', to: 'campaigns#show'
post '/cam_enquiry', to: 'campaigns#cam_enquiry'

constraints subdomain: 'app' do
  get 'campaigns/test', to: 'contoroller#action'
  get '/*any', to: redirect(subdomain: '')
end
```

Comment: It helped me to redirect any requests on 'app.example.com' to `example.com`. I want one more thing that campaigns page should not open on `example.com` it should only be accessible on `app.example.com`

Comment: @Sonalkumarsute, updated the answer, check it, please

Comment: @Sonalkumarsute, sorry, looks like I forgot about one more constraint. Updated the answer again